# Join two collections of different types but the same length

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best way to join two collections of equal size using linq?

Pseudo code example using a for loop:

```
var ints = new[] {1, 2, 3};
var strings = new[] {"one", "two", "three"};

for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
{
    somecollection.add(new[] {Number = ints[i], Word = strings[i]});
}
```

I've looked at joins but I fall over when doing the join because the two types are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this?

```
var union = ints.Select(i => i)
                .Zip(strings, (i1, i2) => new { Number = i1, Word = i2 });
union.ToList()
     .ForEach(z => Console.WriteLine($"Number: {z.Number}, Word: {z.Word}"));
```